# Is there a data type for time format hh:mm:ss in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions, udf

I am processing the files that contains the call details of different users. In the data file, there is a field  `call_duration` which contains the value in the format `hh:mm:ss`. eg: `00:49:39`, `00:20:00` etc

I would like to calculate the the total call duration of each user per month.

I do not see a data type in hive which can stock the time format in `hh:mm:ss`. ( Currently I have this data as string in my staging table).

I am thinking of writing a **UDF** which converts the time into seconds, so that i can do a sum(`call_duration`) grouping by user.

Did any one face a similar situation? Should I go with writing a **UDF** for is there a better approach?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

Storing duration as an Integer number of seconds seems like the best option for efficiency and for being able to do calcuations. I don't think you need a custom UDF to convert from your String to an Int. It can be done by combining existing UDFS:

```
Select 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds as duration_seconds
FROM (
  Select 
  cast(substr(duration,1,2) as Int) as hours, 
  cast(substr(duration,4,2) as Int) as minutes,
  cast(substr(duration,7,2) as Int) as seconds
  From(
    Select "01:02:03" as duration) a
) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive provides built-in date functions to extract hour, minutes and seconds.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

But if these functions doesn't help you directly and you use many combination of builtin function then i would suggest you to write your own UDF (in case this is very frequent utility and you run over large number of rows). You will see query performance difference.

Hope this helps